# Wildfly - Possible registration points for this capability: /socket-binding-group=*/socket-binding=*

Tags: migration, wildfly

after migrating Wildfly 8.2.1.Final to 21.0.0.Final I tried to run the app on the new server (21.0.0)
but I got an error

**Standalone.xml**

```
  <stacks default="tcp">
                <stack name="udp">
                    <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp">
                        <property name="port_range">50</property>
                    </transport>
                    <protocol type="PING" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="MERGE3" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <socket-protocol type="FD_SOCK" module="org.jgroups" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
                    <protocol type="FD_ALL" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="UNICAST3" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="UFC" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="MFC" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
                    <protocol type="RSVP" module="org.jgroups"/>
                </stack>
                <stack name="tcp">
                    <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp">
                        <property name="port_range">50</property>
                    </transport>
                    <protocol type="org.jgroups.protocols.TCPPING" module="org.jgroups">
                        <property name="timeout">3000</property>
                        <property name="initial_hosts">127.0.0.1[7600]</property>
                        <property name="port_range">0</property>
                        <property name="num_initial_members">1</property>
                    </protocol>
                    <protocol type="MERGE3" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <socket-protocol type="FD_SOCK" module="org.jgroups" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
                    <protocol type="FD" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="UNICAST3" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="MFC" module="org.jgroups"/>
                    <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
                    <protocol type="RSVP" module="org.jgroups"/>
                </stack>
            </stacks>
```

**Standalone-ha.xml**

```
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" interface="private" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" interface="private" port="7600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" interface="private" port="57600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" interface="private" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" interface="private" port="54200"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.modcluster.multicast.address:224.0.1.105}" multicast-port="23364"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

the error log

```
18:57:05,340 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/transport=TCP' are not available:
        org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.jgroups-tcp; Possible registration points for this capability: 
            /socket-binding-group=*/socket-binding=*
    18:57:05,340 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=jgroups/stack=udp/protocol=FD_SOCK' are not available:
        org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.jgroups-udp-fd; Possible registration points for this capability: 
            /socket-binding-group=*/socket-binding=*
    18:57:05,340 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=jgroups/stack=udp/transport=UDP' are not available:
        org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.jgroups-udp; Possible registration points for this capability: 
            /socket-binding-group=*/socket-binding=*
    18:57:05,341 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/protocol=FD_SOCK' are not available:
        org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.jgroups-udp-fd; Possible registration points for this capability: 
            /socket-binding-group=*/socket-binding=*
    18:57:05,343 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Comment: I guess those are 2 parts of the same configuration file right ? Could you share your full xml config ? Is the private interface properly defined ?

Comment: no those two are from separate files one for Standalone, the other for Standalone-ha

Comment: in your standalone.xml you are referencing socket-bindings which are defined in your standalone-ha.xml but you need them defined properly in standalone.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out I should include missing socket binding definition inside **Standalone.xml** itself

```
</server>
.......
.....
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8010}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4714"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4715"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="messaging">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="5445"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```